# Accessing contents of AAR file from a java file

Tags: android, nativescript

Is it possible for Java files in a NativeScript-Angular project to access classes in an aar file? When I try to access it I get that the package doesn't exist. I am able to access the package fine via Typescript.

```
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 6.5.0 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/core has 6.5.1 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 6.5.0 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-ios has 6.5.0 version and is up to date.
```

I have the following files:
src/platforms/android/java/com/tns/MyTest.java
src/platforms/android/myplugin.aar

which look like:

```
// mytest.java
package com.tns

public class MyTest extends org.test.MyPlugin {
}
// myplugin.aar
package org.test;
```

```
public class MyPlugin {
}
```

Describe the bug:

```
/private/var/folders/t7/rx02k1ld6bj79sb2nfnzhz200000gn/T/android-project120231-57293-npj215.wvok/MyTest/src/main/java/com/tns/MyTest.java:4: error: package org.test does not exist
public class MyTest extends org.test.MyPlugin {
```

I was under the assumption that since javascript files can just access the contents of the aar file (after generating types) that java files would be able to as well.

Comment: Did you try accessing the classes from AAR within your project in JS / TS? Did it work?

Comment: Yes, I am able to use the classes from the AAR within the Typescript code. I am running into this error only from the Java files.

Comment: Have you added the Java file under sourceSets in gradle?